# How to express that a method in a library is pure?

Tags: .net, code-contracts

Given the case when you need to call a method of a library  that you can't modify in a `Contract.Requires`, (v.g., the method `Regex.Matches`) there is a way to indicate this method is pure?

```
 Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Regex.Matches(password, "\d").Count > 1)
```

Warning:    Detected call to method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(System.String,System.String)' without [Pure] in contracts of method

Comment: Are you sure that the method in question _is_ Pure? If it isn't then you're potentially invalidating your contracts.

Comment: Since I only querying if a string meets a regex pattern, no side effects are expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is not possible.  Microsoft would decorate the signatures of methods like this to offer a better integration with code contracts.